# Pandas conditional split

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I want to split a column in pandas dataframe and I am using this code:

```
df['entry'] = df['entry'].str.split('.')
```

Now the problem is that I want to split bigger text elements such as:

> I am content. I am another content.

But in the data there is also stuff like this:

> I am 10.2 content.

I don't want to split the numbers. So I would need some conditional such as:

If dot between numbers, don't split.

How can I do this with pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use negative [lookarround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

Update to deal with " I am St. Content."

```
rx = re.compile(r'(?<!\d)(?<!\b\w\w)\.(?!\d)')
str = 'I am content. I am another content. I am 10.2 content. I am St. Content.'
str = rx.split(str)
print(str)
```

**Output:**

```
['I am content', ' I am another content', ' I am 10.2 content', ' I am St. Content', '']
```

Comment: If I have another exception such as: I am St. Content. And it is always the two letters St where I don't want to split. Can I add a second lockaround?

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution looked promising but doesn't work on my data.